# How can I optimize this code for large amount of input?

Tags: python

How can I optimize this code for large amount of input? Out of 5, 3 test case are failing because code is taking too long to execute.

```py
n = int(input())
phonebook=dict([map(str,raw_input().split()) for x in range(n)])
while True:
  try:
    name = raw_input()
  except EOFError as e:
    break
  if name not in phonebook.keys():
    print("Not found")
  else:
    print(name +"="+phonebook[name])
```

Comment: As a side note, if you are learning to code in Python, you should really use Python 3, not Python 2 as you do here. Python 2 is no longer supported since January 2020.

Answer (score 0):

This line is probably taking too much time:

`if name not in phonebook.keys():`

Because you are going over all the keys in the dictionary and compare it with input. You can use `in` keyword to check if a key exists directly without iterating over keys

```
n = int(input())
phonebook=dict([map(str,raw_input().split()) for x in range(n)])
while True:
  try:
    name = raw_input()  
  except EOFError as e:
    break
  if name not in phonebook:
    print("Not found")
  else:
    print(name +"="+phonebook[name])
```

Or you can use exception handling on key error like so, it is better practice:

```
n = int(input())
phonebook=dict([map(str,raw_input().split()) for x in range(n)])
while True:
  try:
    name = raw_input()
    print(name +"="+phonebook[name])
  except EOFError as e:
    break
  except KeyError as e:
    print ("Not found")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can turn the phonebook's keys into a set, sets are faster at lookup than lists

Answer (score 0):

last 4 line in one

```
    print(name +"="+phonebook[name]) if phonebook.get(name) else print("Not found")
```